# How to receive SMS in Android foreground Activity and in background?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am receiving SMS.I want ListView to be updated as soon as SMS is received or when Activity is in the foreground.I have done this successfully as I have registered and unregistered receiver in OnResume and OnPause respectively as shown in the Code.:

```
BroadcastReceiver IncomingSMS =  new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {

            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


            if (bundle != null) {

                //—retrieve the SMS message received—
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                    timestamp = smsMessage[n].getTimestampMillis();

                    number = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                    body += smsMessage[n].getDisplayMessageBody();
                    display_name = Util.getContactName(context, number);
                    DBmanager = new DbManager(context);
                    cursor = DBmanager.Return_All_Contacts();
                    String [] contactArr = showcontactsInfo(cursor);
                    Toast.makeText(context, contactArr[0]+"", 3000).show();
                    if(contactArr.length==0)
                    {}
                    else{
                        for(int i= 0;i<=contactArr.length;i++)
                        {

                            abortBroadcast();

                        }
                        blockMessage(context);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }};

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(IncomingSMS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //registerReceiver(IncomingSMS, null);
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(IncomingSMS, filter);
        updateList();

    }
```

I have also registered Receiver in the Manifest file to receive SMS when Activity is in the background.If Activity is in the background and I switch to that Activity then ListView is updated normally but if Activity is in the foreground then ListView has updated data twice. Its most probably that when Activity is in foreground two Receivers are triggered i.e the one in the foreground and second that in the manifest. How can I handle it ???? I want foreground Activity to update to receive SMS only once.
This is how I have registered Receiver in manifest and utilized in java class :

```
public class IncomingSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
DbManager DBmanager;
private long timestamp;
private String number;
static String body = "";
String msg="";
Cursor cursor;
String display_name;
String flag;
ChatActivity obj_chat;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


            if (bundle != null) {

                //—retrieve the SMS message received—
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                    timestamp = smsMessage[n].getTimestampMillis();
                    number = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                    body += smsMessage[n].getDisplayMessageBody();
                    display_name = Util.getContactName(context, number);
                    DBmanager = new DbManager(context);
                    cursor = DBmanager.Return_All_Contacts();
                    String [] contactArr = showcontactsInfo(cursor);
                Toast.makeText(context, contactArr[0]+"", 3000).show();
                    if(contactArr.length==0)
                    {}
                    else{
                    for(int i= 0;i<=contactArr.length;i++)
                    {

                        abortBroadcast();

                            }
                    blockMessage(context);

                    }
                        }
                    }

                }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }

            } // end for loop
        // bundle is null




    private String[] showcontactsInfo(Cursor cursor) {
        String[] contact = new String [cursor.getCount()];
        int i= 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            contact[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            i++;
        }
        return contact;
    }
    private void blockMessage(Context context) {

        // instantiate DbMNager object to insert sms in database
        //formating receiving time:
        //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d  HH:mm:ss a");
        String formatedTime = formatter.format(timestamp);
        flag = "0";
        DBmanager= new DbManager(context);
        DBmanager.open();
        DBmanager.Insert_sms_data(formatedTime ,display_name,body,flag);
        DBmanager.close();
        obj_chat = new ChatActivity();
        obj_chat.updateList();
        msg+= "SMS from " + number + " \n";
        msg += body + " \n";
        msg += formatedTime + " \n";
        msg += flag + " \n";
        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ display_name + "; message: " + body);
        Toast.makeText(context,msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "New message received in Discrete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you have register the `BroadcastReceiver` in menifest then why you are registering it in the activity too.

Comment: i might be wrong but i want to get ListView updated when this Activity is in forground. As soon as message is received it should update ListView which is in foreground .

Comment: If you have register 'BroadcastReceiver' in menifest then it will handle foreground and background both scenario . So remove registering  receiver from activity and check it. let me know if you still have problem

Comment: if ListView having received SMS is in foreground then on receiving new SMS app crashes.

Comment: it seems that `obj_chat.updateList()` called from background thread. just wrap your code from method `updateList` in `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: see [this](http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?s=runOnUiThread) . paste you `updateList` code in `run` block.

Comment: obj_chat.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
     obj_chat.updateList();
    }});
   tried this but still same result.

Comment: put your `updateList()` code